# Guid is bound to string array with one Guid in MVC binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding, guid

I have noticed strange behavior in MVC binding. Let's say I have ViewModel passing data into / from my View. Shipping can have many PaymenTypes (of type ItemViewModel). Example:

```
public class ShippingViewModel
{
    public ItemViewModel[] PaymentTypes { get; set; }
}

public class ItemViewModel
{
    public ItemViewModel()
    {
    }

    public ItemViewModel(Guid key, string value, bool isActive)
    {
        Key = key;
        Value = value;
        IsActive = isActive;
    }

    public object Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

In my view I have checkboxes for all payment types (I did not want to use multiple dropdown because of design).

```
        @{ int order = 0;}
        @foreach (var item in Model.PaymentTypes)
        {
            <div class="checkbox-group">
                @Html.Hidden("PaymentTypes[" + order + "].Key", item.Key)
                @Html.Label("PaymentTypes[" + order + "].IsActive", item.Value, new { @class = "sectioncheckboxhelp" })
                @if (item.IsActive)
                {
                    @Html.CheckBox("PaymentTypes[" + order + "].IsActive", new { @class = "form-control sectioncheckbox", @checked = "checked" })
                }
                else
                {
                    @Html.CheckBox("PaymentTypes[" + order + "].IsActive", new { @class = "form-control sectioncheckbox" })
                }

            </div>

            order++;
        }
```

Everything works good but after posting to my controller action, Key is not Guid but string array **with one key that is Guid**.

Expected:

- Key: Guid (object of course)

But I have

- Key: string[]    where string[0] is of type Guid as a string

When I use the same solution for integer values, everything works well. **Any Idea why is Guid from view binding to object array?**

[image]

Comment: Change `public object Key { get; set; }` to `public Guid Key { get; set; }` and you really should be using a `for` loop (not a `foreach` loop) - it will also cut you code in half

Comment: Yes, that works but I want to have universal ItemViewModel with key as object. Because some of my items are int, another Guid.